# Can't Use PrimeFaces Component on the html page - They aren't rendered at all

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF1.2 and trying to integrate with PrimeFaces1.1. I added the primefaces-1.1.jar file to my META-INF\lib folder. I also added the namespace to the page with "xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui". The page is working but primefaces components arent rendered. Also eclipse doesnt show me components when I write < p: (ctrl+space).  How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a typo, but the jar should be put in WEB-INF/lib instead of META-INF/lib.